# Android notifications fail sound and vibration

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have a problem with Android notifications. I want them to appear and emit sound and vibration, but neither sound nor vibration works. What can be wrong?

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notification
    = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.trisqueta)
        .setStyle(messagingStyle)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
```

Comment: Have You created a notification channel? Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) out.

Comment: Yes, notifications work ok, but sound an vibration no work

Comment: Ok, then please post Your notification channel settings as well.

Comment: private void createChannels(){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }